# How to get the key of a key/value JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a JS object like:

```
var foo = { 'bar' : 'baz' }
```

If I know that `foo` has that basic key/value structure, but don't know the name of the key, How can I get it? `for ... in`? `$.each()`?

Comment: what is wrong with for ... in?

Comment: It feels indirect and you have to use hasOwnProperty. I guess I'll make a library function that does it....

Answer (score 98, accepted):

If you want to get all keys, [ECMAScript 5 introduced `Object.keys`](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.2.3.14). This is only supported by newer browsers but the [MDC documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) provides an alternative implementation (which also uses `for...in` btw):

```
if(!Object.keys) Object.keys = function(o){
     if (o !== Object(o))
          throw new TypeError('Object.keys called on non-object');
     var ret=[],p;
     for(p in o) if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,p)) ret.push(p);
     return ret;
}
```

Of course if you want both, key and value, then `for...in` is the only reasonable solution.

Comment: `p` gives me the key but how do I get the value of the key? Thanks.

Comment: For both keys and values, use the new Object.entries() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: perhaps it's an indication of my limited understanding, but this answer seems incredibly verbose (admittedly reusable) for something as simple as getting a key/value. Shouldn't @Michael Benin answer be marked as the best one?

Comment: Erm... does anyone else clicking the first link get redirected to narcotics anonymous?

Answer (score 255):

You would iterate inside the object with a for loop:

```
for(var i in foo){
  alert(i); // alerts key
  alert(foo[i]); //alerts key's value
}
```

Or

```
Object.keys(foo)
  .forEach(function eachKey(key) { 
    alert(key); // alerts key 
    alert(foo[key]); // alerts value
  });
```

Comment: What if I don’t want`foo[i]`to be`"_proto_"`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Comment: What if I don’t want to alert()`foo[i]`if`i`is`some string`?

Comment: @user2284570: i can be a string - no problem.

Comment: don't you mean for(var i in Object.keys(foo)) {

Comment: What if there is an array of objects

Answer (score 139):

You can access each key individually without iterating as in:

```
var obj = { first: 'someVal', second: 'otherVal' };
alert(Object.keys(obj)[0]); // returns first
alert(Object.keys(obj)[1]); // returns second
```

Comment: You can now use spread operator for this purpose, it looks better:

```const [firstKey, ...rest] = Object.keys(obj);```

Answer (score 90):

Given your Object:

```
var foo = { 'bar' : 'baz' }
```

To get `bar`, use:

```
Object.keys(foo)[0]
```

To get `baz`, use:

```
foo[Object.keys(foo)[0]]
```

Assuming a single object

Comment: another way `const [key, value] = Object.entries(foo)[0];`

Answer (score 40):

This is the simplest and easy way. This is how we do this.

```js
var obj = { 'bar' : 'baz' }
var key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
var value = obj[key];
     
 console.log("key = ", key) // bar
 console.log("value = ", value) // baz
```

Object.keys() is javascript method which return an array of keys when using on objects.

```
Object.keys(obj) // ['bar']
```

Now you can iterate on the objects and can access values like below-

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach( function(key) {
  console.log(obj[key]) // baz
})
```

Comment: You may get `TypeError` if you expect a key to be a number. Because keys are always strings.

Comment: @Green, Why would you expect a key to be a number ?

Answer (score 38):

A *one liner* for you:

```
const OBJECT = {
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2',
    'key3': 'value3',
    'key4': 'value4'
};

const value = 'value2';

const key = Object.keys(OBJECT)[Object.values(OBJECT).indexOf(value)];

window.console.log(key); // = key2
```

Comment: that's a naaasty one-liner, very powerful, thank you

Answer (score 28):

```
// iterate through key-value gracefully
const obj = { a: 5, b: 7, c: 9 };
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  console.log(`${key} ${value}`); // "a 5", "b 7", "c 9"
}
```

Refer MDN

Comment: Highly underrated answer. You can also use the functional approach, `Object.entries(object1).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(\`${key}: ${value}\`);
})`

Answer (score 20):

I was having the same problem and this is what worked

```
//example of an Object
var person = {
    firstName:"John",
    lastName:"Doe",
    age:50,
    eyeColor:"blue"
};

//How to access a single key or value
var key = Object.keys(person)[0];
var value = person[key];
```

Comment: why not `var value = person[key];` ?  That way you don't have to know the key of the value you want to pull.

Answer (score 14):

best way to get key/value of object.

```js
let obj = {
        'key1': 'value1',
        'key2': 'value2',
        'key3': 'value3',
        'key4': 'value4'
    }
    Object.keys(obj).map(function(k){ 
    console.log("key with value: "+k +" = "+obj[k])    
    
    })
```

Answer (score 9):

I don't see anything else than `for (var key in foo)`.

Answer (score 5):

Since you mentioned `$.each()`, here's a handy approach that would work in jQuery 1.6+:

```
var foo = { key1: 'bar', key2: 'baz' };

// keys will be: ['key1', 'key2']
var keys = $.map(foo, function(item, key) {
  return key;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to just use Underscore.js:

> **keys**
>
> _.keys(object)
> Retrieve all the names of the object's properties.
>
> _.keys({one : 1, two : 2, three : 3});
> => ["one", "two", "three"]

Yes, you need an extra library, but it's so easy!

Comment: @lonesomeday yes, but underscore/lodash are useful in many other ways, so it's worth bringing up.

Answer (score 4):

use for each loop for accessing keys in Object or Maps in javascript

```
for(key in foo){
   console.log(key);//for key name in your case it will be bar
   console.log(foo[key]);// for key value in your case it will be baz
}
```

**Note:** you can also use

> Object.keys(foo);

it will give you like this
output:

[bar];

Answer (score 4):

**Object.keys()**
The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

```
var arr1 = Object.keys(obj);
```

**Object.values()**
The Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

```
var arr2 = Object.values(obj);
```

For more please go [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way other than `for ... in`. If you don't want to use that (parhaps because it's marginally inefficient to have to test `hasOwnProperty` on each iteration?) then use a different construct, e.g. an array of kvp's:

```
[{ key: 'key', value: 'value'}, ...]
```

Answer (score 2):

Well `$.each` is a library construct, whereas `for ... in` is native js, which should be better

Answer (score 2):

You can use Object.keys functionality to get the keys like:

```js
const tempObjects={foo:"bar"}

Object.keys(tempObjects).forEach(obj=>{
   console.log("Key->"+obj+ "value->"+tempObjects[obj]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Readable and simple solution:

```js
const object1 = {
    first: 'I am first',
    second: 'I am second'
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}

// expected output:
// "first: I am first"
// "second: I am second"
```

Answer (score 0):

for showing as a string, simply use:

```
console.log("they are: " + JSON.stringify(foo));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **AWS CloudFront Functions** then this would work for you.

```
function handler(event) {
    var response = event.response;
    var headers = response.headers;
    if("x-amz-meta-csp-hash" in headers){ 
        hash=headers["x-amz-meta-csp-hash"].value;
        console.log('hash is ' + hash);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla JavaScript Solution

You can use `Object.entries()` & `.map()`.

```js
const myData = {
    name: 'Amoos',
    age: 28,
    skills: [
      { id: 1, value: "React" },
      { id: 2, any_label: "PHP" }
    ],
    booleanKey: false,
    ignoredKey: true
}

const getKeyValue = (data, keys=[], nestedKey='value') => {
  let result = ''
  const resp = Object.entries(data).map( item => {
    const [key, val] = item
    if(!keys.includes(key)) return
    
    if(!!val && typeof val === "object") { 
      const innerResp = val.map( v => {
        return v.value || v[nestedKey]
      } )
      result += `${key}: ${innerResp.join(' ')} \n`
      return
    }
    result += `${key}: ${val} \n`
  })
  return result
}

console.log( 
  getKeyValue(myData, ['name', 'age', 'skills', 'booleanKey'], 'any_label')
)
```