# Get key using value from an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, hashmap

```
c =      {
            "UNKNOWN_ERR" : 0,
            "INDEX_SIZE_ERR" : 1,
            "DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR" : 2,
            "HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR" : 3,
            "WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR" : 4,
            "INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR" : 5,
            "NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR" : 6,
            "NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR" : 7,
            "NOT_FOUND_ERR" : 8,
            "NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR" : 9}
```

To get the value using the key is easy, I just use the key in `c["UNKNOWN_ERR"]` to get `0`, given that all the values are unique is safe to get the key (message) from the value(errorcode).

Is there a standard way to do that or do I need to write a function that looks in all key and search that specific value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [best way to get the key of a key/value javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268679/best-way-to-get-the-key-of-a-key-value-javascript-object)

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907419/how-to-get-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-by-its-value

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As you already assumed you need to iterate over the object's attributes and check the value.

```
for(var key in c) {
    if(c[key] === whatever) {
        // do stuff with key
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

es6 `find` method:

```
const getKey = (obj,val) => Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key] === val);
```

in your case

```
console.log(getKey(c,1)); // INDEX_SIZE_ERR
```

Comment: This doesn't work when the value is 0

Answer (score 6):

[Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) provides a more easy solution to this

You can get key using this code also

```
var errKey = _.invert(c)[errCode];
```

for e.x. if you use errCode = 3 as shown below

```
var errKey = _.invert(c)[3];
```

then

`errKey` will be `HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR`

Answer (score 2):

Try [findKey()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#findKey) lodash method:

```
var key = _.findKey(c, v => v === val)
```

where val - property value.

Comment: The original question does not seem to ask about external libraries.