# Simple way of getting object key from JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way of getting the `key` from an standard/json object without having to use a `for` loop?

e.g.

```
var $Object = {"Key":"Value"};
getKeyAsString($Object["Key"]); //return str "Key"
```

Comment: `{"Key" => "Value"}`  not a valid js object

Comment: There is no JSON here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a single object

```
var $Object = {Key : "Value"};
```

To get `key`, use:

```
Object.keys($Object)[0]
```

To get `Value`, use:

```
$Object[Object.keys($Object)[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there *will* be a loop, but it doesn't have to be in your code:

```js
var obj = { key: "value" };
var k = Object.keys(obj)[0];
console.log(k);      // "key"
console.log(obj[k]); // "value"
```

`Object.keys` finds all of the own enumerable properties of the object (the ones named by strings, not `Symbol`s) and returns an array of their names.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't

```js
var $Object = { key: 'value1', 'key-1': 'value of key-1'};
  
console.log($Object.key);
console.log($Object['key']);
               
console.log($Object['key-1']);
```

do it? If the object (only arrays) is not associative. you can access it using index starting from 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here a valid response : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6268840/5013024

use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/keys)