# Get key/values from JSON array of objects without knowing the key name

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to build a HTML table with data from a JSON structured array such as:

```
var myjson = [
{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
{"firstName":"Peter","lastName": "Jones"}
];
```

I know I can use:

```
var tbl = "<table>"

            $.each(myjson, function(x, y) {
                tbl += "<tr>";
                  tbl += "<td>firstName</td>";
                  tbl += "<td>lastName</td>";  
                tbl += "</tr>"; 
                tbl += "<tr>";
                  tbl += "<td>" + y.firstName + "</td>";
                  tbl += "<td>" + y.lastName + "</td>";  
                tbl += "</tr>"; 
              });

tbl += "</table>";
```

but how can I get the same result if I don't know what the column names (firstName, lastName) are called? How can I iterate through the key/values of each object in the JSON structured array?

In each array, the number of elements in each object will be the same

Comment: [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) Will give you an array of the objects own properties. You could then iterate that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [best way to get the key of a key/value javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268679/best-way-to-get-the-key-of-a-key-value-javascript-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`Object.keys`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the `keys` of the `object`.

> ***Object.keys()*** method returns an **array** of strings that represent all the **enumerable properties** of the given object.

Use `index` of `array` to decide `header` of table

```js
var myjson = [{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe"
}, {
  "firstName": "Anna",
  "lastName": "Smith"
}, {
  "firstName": "Peter",
  "lastName": "Jones"
}];
var tbl = "<table>";
$.each(myjson, function(x, y) {
  var keys = Object.keys(y);
  if (!x) {
    tbl += "<tr>";
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
      tbl += "<th>" + key + "</th>";
    });
    tbl += "</tr>";
  }
  tbl += "<tr>";
  keys.forEach(function(key) {
    tbl += "<td>" + y[key] + "</td>";
  });
  tbl += "</tr>";
});

tbl += "</table>";
$('body').append(tbl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use `for...in` loop.

```
for(let key in myjson[0]) console.log(key + ' == ' + myjson[0][key]);
```

Here is how you code should looks like (see also [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zexmj3xh/)):

```
var myjson = [{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe"
}, {
  "firstName": "Anna",
  "lastName": "Smith"
}, {
  "firstName": "Peter",
  "lastName": "Jones"
}];

var keys = [];
for(let key in myjson[0]) keys.push(key);

var tbl = "<table>"

$.each(myjson, function() {
  tbl += "<tr>";
  for(let index in keys) tbl += '<td>' + keys[index] + '</td>';
  tbl += "</tr>";
  tbl += "<tr>";
  for(let index in keys) tbl += '<td>' + arguments[1][keys[index]] + '</td>';
  tbl += "</tr>";
});

tbl += "</table>";

document.body.innerHTML = tbl;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it only gave me a list of the index numbers

Comment: @PeterJQuinn. Did you try it on JSFiddle? It works as you expected, the indexes you get you can use as property names of your object.

Comment: Apologies @SoftwareEngineer171, this does show me results, but it creates rows with the keys every other row. I know I didn't specify not to do this and it'd be easy enough to eliminate this anyway. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this

```
       var tbl = "<table>"
        $.each(myjson, function(x, y) {
            keys = Object.keys(y);
            tbl += "<tr>";
            $.each(keys, function(i,key){
              tbl += "<td>" + key + "</td>";
            }) 
            tbl += "</tr><tr>"; 
            $.each(keys, function(i,key){
              tbl += "<td>" + y[key] + "</td>";
            }) 
            tbl += "</tr>"; 
          });
         tbl += "</table>";
```

You can further bring down to one loop if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/1926/)

```
tbl += "<tr>";
                        for(var i=0;i<Object.keys(myjson[0]).length; i++)
            {                           
                  tbl += "<td>"+Object.keys(myjson[0])[i]+"</td>";                               
             }
            tbl += "</tr>";
```