# Getting values from Array Object

Tags: javascript, json

How do I access the values "CFTO-A","CFTO-B", "CFTO-C", "CFTO-D" in this object.

The object comes from this:

```
 console.log(JSON.parse(data[0]['content']['message'])['gtmstate'][36]);
```

[image: Object Details]

I've tried using `Object.keys` but that only prints the TOP key of `JSON.parse(data[0]['content']['message'])['gtmstate'][36]`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268679/best-way-to-get-the-key-of-a-key-value-javascript-object

Comment: will your objects have only one key all the time

Comment: @Geeky - yes as far as I know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var arr = JSON.parse(data[0]['content']['message'])['gtmstate'][36]
$.each(arr,function(i,data){
$.each(data,function(j,kal){
console.log(j+"-------"+kal)
})
})
```

Comment: I want to dynamically get the value, not have to hard code it, the keys can change from my data source

Comment: Result:

0-------[object Object] 
1-------[object Object]
2-------[object Object]  
3-------[object Object]

Comment: console.log arr and see to it its an array or object

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet

```js
var arr = [{
  "CFTO-A": 10
}, {
  "CFTO-B": 20
}, {
  "CFTO-C": 30
}, {
  "CFTO-D": 40
}];
arr.forEach(function(item) {
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
    alert(key);
  })
})
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript [Array map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

**Working Demo :**

```js
var jsonObj = [{
  "CFTO-A": 10
}, {
  "CFTO-B": 20
}, {
  "CFTO-C": 30
}, {
  "CFTO-D": 40
}];

var resArray = [];
jsonObj.map(function(item) {
  Object.keys(item).map(function(data) {
    resArray.push(item[data]);
  })
});

console.log(resArray);
```