# How to get a key/value pair for an object

Tags: javascript, json

This question may sound very stupid, but I want to get a key/value pair for my object:

```
var a = {"e":1,"d":3,"f":4}
```

I tried with `Object.keys(a) // returns ["e", "d", "f"]`

this does not get me the values associated with the keys, how can I get both to be able to display in a page.

html:

```
<div>
  <img src={value}/> //here i want value 1 to be displayed
{key} //with "e"
</div>
```

how do I do it? Thanks!!

Comment: `Object.values` for just the values or maybe use `Object.entries` to get the key/value pairs.

Comment: `Object.entries(a).forEach(([key, value]) => do stuff)`

Comment: Thanks all for your help and answers, it helped me a lot!!!!

Comment: if you know the key, just use the key to access the value...  object[key]  gives the value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [best way to get the key of a key/value javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268679/best-way-to-get-the-key-of-a-key-value-javascript-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go. To get `key/value pair` from an object, do it like below using pure JavaScript way [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
var a = {"e":1,"d":3,"f":4}

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(a)) {
  console.log(`${key} ${value}`);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**If you want to get a single value:**

```
Just use: *a.e* or *a[e]* return 1 

eg. <img src={a.e} />
```

**If you want to iterate an Object to get value there several ways:**

```
var a = {"e":1,"d":3,"f":4}
```

**Method 1:** Using for:

```
for ( var x in a) {
    console.log('v:',a[x]);
}
```

**Method 2:** Using map:

```
Object.keys(a).map( (k) => {console.log('k',a[k])} );
```

**Method 3:** Using foreach:

```
Object.keys(a).forEach(function(key,index) {
        console.log('a[key]',a[key]);
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do it is like this:

```
var a = {"e":1,"d":3,"f":4}

 for(var key in a){
  alert(key + ' : ' + a[key])
 }
```

If you need to iterate over each pair that is. However for in loops are kind of janky in javascript and you should read a bit about going that route if you decide to.

https://jsfiddle.net/edh4131/hd9p7cxq/

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = {"e":1,"d":3,"f":4}
let container = document.querySelector('.container')

Object.entries(a).forEach(entry =>{
 let div = document.createElement('div')
  let img = document.createElement('img')
  img.src = entry[1]
  div.textContent = entry[0]
  div.appendChild(img)
  
  container.appendChild(div)
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
</div>
```