# Access a unique ID in firebase realtime database with AppScript?

Tags: google-apps-script, firebase-realtime-database

take a look at this screenshot of my Firebase Realtime Database:

[image: Screenshot of Firebase real-time database]

As you can see, I've got a node name 'Notifications', under that, there is another node with a unique ID, how do I access this node with AppScript, here is a picture of what I've done so far:

[image: Screenshot of the AppScript code]

And here is a screenshot of what's being retrieved:

[image: Retrieved data]

Appreciate the feedback! :)

Comment: OK, so what exactly are you trying to do with this result?

Comment: I want to delete the node named newbie

Comment: I suggest editing the question to more accurately describe what you're trying to accomplish. The question doesn't saying anything about deleting a node.

Comment: Yeah to delete the node, you need to access it and that’s what my questions is about

Comment: Does this answer your question? [best way to get the key of a key/value javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268679/best-way-to-get-the-key-of-a-key-value-javascript-object)

Comment: Hey man, thanks a lotttttt!!!! Exactly what I was looking for, have a good day!